# How to filter foreach array for integers

Tags: php, sql

I have a for-each statement based off a php generated query..

I am trying to figure out how I can make sure all the IDDestinations of the records are the same.

For example in my current query I have 2 records with an IDDestination of 12, one record with an IDDestination of 9 and the last is 3.

I know how to do this in the query but I am trying to generate a message to the user if the IDDestinations are not equivalent.

My code so far.

```
foreach($results as $row) {
    $IDDestination =(int) $row['IDDestination'];
    if ($IDDestination == $IDDestination){
        echo "<script>alert('All Courses Match Destination.');</script>";
    } else {
        echo "<script>alert('Courses have different Destinations);</script>";
    }
    var_dump($IDDestination);
}
```

This is currently just verifying that each record has an IDDestination Present and tells ME All courses Match.

How can I make it so the INTEGERS are equivalent and give me the same message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way; use a variable outside your loop to determine if it's ok or not:

```
$everything_matches = true;
$id = null;

foreach($results as $row) {
    // Set it for the first record.
    if($id === null)
        $id = $row['IDDestination'];

    // If the current iteration's ID matches the first record, $everything_matches
    // will stay true, otherwise it's false and we should kill the loop.
    if($id != $row['IDDestination']) {
        $everything_matches = false;
        break;
    }
}

// Output your message
$message = $everything_matches ? 'All courses match destination.' : 'Courses have different destinations.';
echo '<script>alert("' . $message . '");</script>';
```

Comment: hey thanks for explaining how it works also, really will help me in the future!